How to ignore errors in files for vscode plugin clang + cmake?
I used the clangd plugin of vscode with cmake to develop C language projects. The clangd plugin provides clang-tidy static detection function.
But I have a requirement: Can I ignore the errors in a certain file instead of warnings?
I have been working on it for a long time, and the answer I got is that I can only ignore warnings, not errors.
this is my setting.json config
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--log=verbose",
        "--compile-commands-dir=${workspaceFolder}/build",
        "--query-driver=D:\\000_soft\\mingw\\bin\\",
    ],

Why is there such a requirement? Because I usually use vscode + clangd + cmake plug-in, but some embedded assembly syntax and compiler embedded macro definitions in the core_m4.h file of st are not supported by clangd, such as::
#if   defined ( __CC_ARM )
  #define __ASM            __asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for ARM Compiler          */
  #define __INLINE         __inline                                   /*!< inline keyword for ARM Compiler       */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static __inline

#elif defined ( __GNUC__ )
  #define __ASM            __asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for GNU Compiler          */
  #define __INLINE         inline                                     /*!< inline keyword for GNU Compiler       */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline

#elif defined ( __ICCARM__ )
  #define __ASM            __asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for IAR Compiler          */
  #define __INLINE         inline                                     /*!< inline keyword for IAR Compiler. Only available in High optimization mode! */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline

#elif defined ( __TMS470__ )
  #define __ASM            __asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for TI CCS Compiler       */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline

#elif defined ( __TASKING__ )
  #define __ASM            __asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for TASKING Compiler      */
  #define __INLINE         inline                                     /*!< inline keyword for TASKING Compiler   */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline

#elif defined ( __CSMC__ )
  #define __packed
  #define __ASM            _asm                                      /*!< asm keyword for COSMIC Compiler      */
  #define __INLINE         inline                                    /*use -pc99 on compile line !< inline keyword for COSMIC Compiler   */
  #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline

#endif
__STATIC_INLINE void __set_CONTROL(uint32_t control)
{
  register uint32_t __regControl         __ASM("control");
  __regControl = control;
}


If there is an error in your code, then its object file will not be created & thus neither will the resultant executable. You can ignore it & continue to process the other files, but you still won't have a final exe.

If you detect that your car does not have an engine and not steering wheel. Can you ignore these errors and still drive away with it? Other than warnings, errors indicate some severe problem with your code. It does not follow mandatory rules of programming and the compiler cannot produce anything that would be possible to be executed afterwards.

Are you really sure about your requirement? Normally it is the other way around: You tell the compiler to treat warnings as error and stop if there are warnings.

Yes, errors can be ignored in clangd, using https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#suppress.

Thanks for your reply. I used
Diagnostics:
Suppress: [‘*’]

to disable diagnostics for all files. Do you have a way to disable diagnostics for a specific file?
